# 3D needle bars and map not rendering when using a slider - plotly/Python

Tags: python, dictionary, 3d, plotly

the code is supposed to lay a basemap and 3d needle bars that change based on the month chosen by the slider. The only thing is that once I did a update_slider() slider code, it just started not showing neither the lines (from plotly .add_collection3d) nor the needles (ax.plot)

Help
[What should render for every months](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6gZ7.png)
[what renders now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiqT1.png)

tried changing the plotting of needles bars by doing ax=plt.gca()

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd 
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np
import ipywidgets as widgets

 
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\alion\Downloads\States_Energy.csv")

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25, 25))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

 
m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-119, llcrnrlat=22, urcrnrlon=-64, urcrnrlat=49,
            projection='lcc', lat_1=33, lat_2=60, lon_0=-100, fix_aspect=False, ax=ax)


# Define the needle bars
lat, lon = m(df["Longitude"], df["Latitude"])
months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']


def update_slider(month_index):
    ax.clear()
    ax.add_collection3d(m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.25, color="black"))
    ax.add_collection3d(m.drawcountries(linewidth=0.75, color="black"))
    ax.add_collection3d(m.drawstates(color='0.5'))

    height = df[months[month_index]]
    colors = cm.plasma(height)
    
    for i in range(len(lon)):
        ax.plot([lat[i], lat[i]], [lon[i], lon[i]], [-20, height[i]], color=colors[i], linewidth=2)
        fig.canvas.draw()

    
widgets.interact(update_slider, month_index=widgets.IntSlider(min=0, max=11, step=1, value=0))
plt.show()
```